# u substitution understaing

Tags: integration

I have the following:

$\frac 13\int(5-3x)^3xdx$

If I sub $u=5-3x$

Then I'll have $-3dx=du$

Which gives me: $\frac 13\int u^3x (-\frac 13)du$

Can someone explain how wolfram gets: $\frac{1}{27}\int(u-5)u^3du$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second to last equation, you should substitute $x$ with $$x=\frac{5-u}{3}$$ which would give the same result as Wolfram.